# mysql query for sorting posts by entry_date based on status

Tags: php, mysql

I want to sort posts by entry_date decreasing order. Some of posts can be in active so I want to sort like active posts should come first based on entry date.

So output should be like below:

```
id  post          entry_date       status
1   abc..         15-april-2012    1
5   xyz           12-april-2012    1 
2   art...        14-april-2012    0
```

How to sort like this ?

Comment: SELECT id, post, entry_date, status FROM table ORDER BY status DESC, entry_date DESC

Comment: @Diego I think you should post this as an answer

Comment: Already tried this but There are not only 2 status. status can have 0,1,2,3 inactive, active approved , disapproved and I want active first then other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY if(status=1,0,1), entry_date desc
```